# btrfs RAID1 - should I create subvolumes which can be mounted separately?

Tags: mount, raid-1, btrfs

I plan to construct a btrfs RAID1 spanning over 2, or maybe 3 devices.

This will mainly be used to hold data for a samba server, but maybe I'd want to add other uses (like mounting `/var/snap/` or `/var/lxd` away from the system disk) later down the road.

In that light ... does it make sense to create a subvolume `samba` on that RAID and mount that subvolume to let's say `/srv/samba` rather then mounting the entire RAID disk?

Like that in my (yet limited) understanding I could add another subvolume (like `varsnap` which I can mount to `/var/snap` when I'd need that) later on to the same big data pool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that way you can apply different storage options that you might not want to apply to other volumes in the future. In the ZFS world the same strategy applies.

Comment: `mkfs.btrfs -d raid1 -m raid1 -f /dev/sdb /dev/sdc`  <br/>

Comment: damn, how do I make an line break in a comment? 2 Spaces at the end (as suggested) doesn't do it. I mean as soon I hit enter after 2 spaces I save the comment instead of going to the new line

Comment: no idea, and I don't remember how to make subvolumes with BTRFS.